# $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function (response) { sends the page in the beginning stage

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

There are 2 radio buttons `H` and `T` in the partial view `_p`.

When the `_p` loads, `H` radio button will be selected by default and its respective `txtH` will be shown. But radio button `H` and `T` works based on show/hide code written in Script which is shown below.

Now, if `T` radio button Selected and its respective textbox filled with some data and If I submit the `_p` now then partial view gets refreshed and goes to beginning stage where `H` was checked by default.

But what I want is that, after page refresh, `T` radio should be selected with `txtT`.

When I debug the code, `$('#mypartial').html(response);` sends the page in the beginning stage.

EDIT: I have edited my question for more clarity. Added some more code in controller section and also added the script to call partial views.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Home(ClsAA clsAA)
{     
    ModelState.Clear();  
    if (Id == "Z01")
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_P.cshtml", clsAA);
    }
    else if (Id == "P02")
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_I.cshtml", clsAA);
    }
    return PartialView();                                        
}
```

Main View

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ProductName)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ProductDetail)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ProductCost)</th>     
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)</td>
            <td >@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductDetail)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductCost)</td>
            <td><input class="search btn-default" type="button" value="Select" data-assigned="@item.ProductCode"/></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<div id="MyReports">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Home", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myform" }))
    {
        <div id="mypartial"></div>              
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Run</button>              
    }
</div>
```

This is how Partial loads

```
$('.search').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('assigned');
    var route = '@Url.Action("PartialView", "Home")?id=' + id;        
    $('#mypartial').load(route)
});
```

Partial View

```
<div class="PContainer">
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.HDT, "H", new { @checked = "checked" })H
    </label>
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.HDT, "T")T
    </label>
</div>
<div class="P">
    <div id="H" class="PHT">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtH)  
    </div>
    <div id="T" class="PHT">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtT)               
    </div>
</div>
```

For radiobutton Script

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $('#MyReports').on('change', '.PContainer input[type = "radio"]', function () {
        var divs = $('.P').find('.PHT');
        var id = $(this).val();
        divs.hide();   
        $('#' + id).show();             
    })
});
```

Scripts for submit

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = '@Url.Action("Home")';
    $('#myform').submit(function () {
        if (!$(this).valid()) {
            return;
        }
        $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
            debugger;
            $('#mypartial').html(response);
            $("#myModal").modal('show');     
        });
        return false;
    })
});
```

Comment: Why are you clearing `ModelState`? - that ensures that the correct radio button will not be selected (remove that from your controller). And your partial should include conditional statements to show/hide the relevant textbox based on the value of `HDT`

Comment: And remove the `new { @checked = "checked" }` from your `RadioButtonFor()` - never set the `checked` attribute - the method does that correctly based on the value of the property

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I removed `ModelState` and checked but still after submission, `H` will be checked.

Comment: If you have selected `T` and submitted the form, and returned the partial back again, then `T` will be selected. But its difficult to understand what you are doing here - what is the point of returning back the same partial you just submitted

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Actually I have more than one partial so I am returning in that way. Here, I have included one partial. I do not know whether this is correct way of returning the partial. Please help!

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Can you please help me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168875/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-raj).